# measuring distance of 2 inches using gps or accelerometer

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, accelerometer, physics

I want to calcuate the displacement of 2 inches. the ipad would be put on the pillow and  be pushed downwards. If the distance moved by ipad is 2i nches then I should detect that. 
I had two option for that. I can double integrate accelerometer and can get the distance but people say that it is quite inaccurate .
I am concerned about the accuracy for the gps also.

So, what the best way to do this task...measuring displacement of 2 inches accurately ?

I think motion detection should be fine also

Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of a good solution for that, but GPS definitely won't work for a distance of 2 inches. Especially because this seems like an indoor use case.

Comment: Here are some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5043563/1488062

Comment: Can I detect motion of 2inches or may 3inches ?

Comment: With GPS this does not work, neither indoors nor outdoors.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app which measures the distance when the iPhone slides down a wide plank.
This app works using the accelerometer.

Very short distances may work with acceleromter, long distances not.

The GPS approach will not work, for many reasons.